# Scrollbar creating overlaping chart div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, bootstrap-4

I'm implementing a button to generate a report (plot some charts). Those charts are `hidden()` before pressing the button, since I'm using `bootstrap` scrollbar is also hidden. After pressing the button I call `show()` on divs that charts are defined and call chart render function, after divs are shown scrollbar is also created but `chart.reflow()` for some reason is getting inaccessible and it won't trigger, so exporting button and credits are getting cropped by scrollbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/m6jqa79r/24/

If you resize the window manually the `.reflow()` is called and it gets fixed. Any workaround or sugestion?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue which you are struggling to is not related to triggering the `chart.reflow`. In the provided demo you are trying to trigger `chart.reflow` before the chart has been initialized - check your dev console.

The true issue is related to your button position. You have used the `style="float: left;"` attribute for your button element, which sets the left position of the button in the window - which is also a container for the first chart and that creates the complication while calculating initial positions of some chart elements - here is a demo where is easier to see what I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L70xh95g/

So you will need to find the other CSS styles which wouldn't disturb the chart rendering. In regular block pattern everything works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dwrje7f0/

I just deleted the `style="float: left;"`

Comment: In my project I have some other elements that go together with 'show report' `button`, removing the `style` from it didn't work. I'm trying to apply your solution to my project.

Comment: @BernardoMarques sounds like maybe other HTML elements have an impact on the chart container and disturb the initial loading. If you will need more help with it - please reproduce your issue.